$\frac{\partial Tr(|X|)}{\partial X}$ on differentiable point
For an $n$ dimension Hermitian matrix $X$, suppose its eigenvalues are $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_n$,$Tr(|X|)=\sum_i|\lambda_i|$. Is there any formula for $\frac{\partial Tr(|X|)}{\partial X}=\left(\frac{\partial Tr(|X|)}{\partial x_{ij}}\right)_{ij}$ on every differentiable point (that is $\forall i,\lambda_i\neq 0$)? For example, when $n=1$, that is $sgn(x)$ when $x\neq 0$.

Check out this paper by Marcus Carlsson about differentiating the modulus of a matrix.  And since the trace of the modulus is the Nuclear Norm, this SE post is relevant.

Be careful about the fact that if you work with Hermitian matrices, you can't differentiate with respect to $x_{ij}$ since $X + \varepsilon E_{ij}$ is not Hermitian when $\varepsilon \neq 0$ and $i \neq j$. (Here, $E_{ij}$ is the matrix whose only non-zero coefficient is a $1$ at position $(i,j)$). You can compute the differential with respect to $X$ Hermitian or partial derivatives with respect to $x_{ii}$, $x_{ij} + x_{ji}$ ($i \neq j$) and $\mathbb{\textbf{i}}(x_{ij} - x_{ji})$ ($i \neq j$) for example.
As in the case $n = 1$, the easiest method is to separate the case of negative and positive values. It is the same with $n$ variables. Set for all integer $0 \leqslant k \leqslant n$, $H_{k,n}$ to be the space of $n \times n$ Hermitian matrices with $k$ positive eigenvalues and $n - k$ negative eigenvalues so each $H_{k,n}$ is an open subset of the space of $n \times n$ Hermitian matrices. Actually, they are the connected components of the set of invertible Hermitian matrices.
Let $X \in H_{k,n}$, let $V_+ \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be the sum of the eigenspaces of $X$ of positive eigenvalues and $V_- \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ the sum of the eigenspaces of $X$ of negative eigenvalues. By the assumption $X \in H_{k,n}$, $\dim(V_+) = k$, $\dim(V_-) = n - k$ and $V_+ \oplus V_- = \mathbb{C}^n$. Moreover, since $X$ is Hermitian, this direct sum is orthogonal and we have,
$$
X = \begin{pmatrix} P & 0 \\ 0 & N \end{pmatrix},
$$
in $\mathbb{C}^n = V_+ \oplus V_-$. Therefore, $P$ is Hermitian definite positive and $N$ is Hermitian definite negative. We see immediately that $\mathbb{tr}(|X|) = \mathbb{tr}(P) - \mathbb{tr}(N)$. Clearly, for all $A,B$ Hermitian,
$$
\mathbb{tr}\left(\left|X + \varepsilon\begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & B \end{pmatrix}\right|\right) = \mathbb{tr}(|X|) + \varepsilon(\mathbb{tr}(A) - \mathbb{tr}(B)),
$$
whenever $|\varepsilon|$ is small enough. And when $C$ is a $k \times (n - k)$ complex matrix, set,
$$
X_\varepsilon = \begin{pmatrix} P & \varepsilon C \\ \varepsilon C^\dagger & N \end{pmatrix}.
$$
By the determinant by blocs formula,
\begin{align*}
\chi_{X_\varepsilon}(T) & = \det(TI_n - X_\varepsilon)\\
& = \begin{vmatrix} TI_k - P & -\varepsilon C \\ -\varepsilon C^\dagger & TI_{n - k} - N \end{vmatrix}\\
& = \det(TI_k - P - \varepsilon C(TI_{n - k} - N)^{-1}\varepsilon C^\dagger)\det(TI_{n - k} - N)\\
& = \det(TI_k - P - \varepsilon^2C(TI_{n - k} - N)^{-1}C^\dagger)\det(TI_{n - k} - N).
\end{align*}
It is a smooth function of $\varepsilon^2$ so the coefficients of this polynomial are smooth functions of $\varepsilon^2$. Since the eigenvalues of $X$ (i.e. the roots of $\chi_X$) are non-zero, the eigenvalues of $X_\varepsilon$ (i.e. the roots of $\chi_{X_\varepsilon}$) are, for $\varepsilon$ close to zero, a smooth function of $\varepsilon^2$. We deduce that,
$$
\mathrm{tr}(|X_\varepsilon|) = \mathrm{tr}(|X|) + \mathrm{O}(\varepsilon^2).
$$
Therefore, in general,
$$
d\mathrm{tr}(|X|)Y = \mathrm{tr}(Y_1) - \mathrm{tr}(Y_3),
$$
if,
$$
Y = \begin{pmatrix} Y_1 & Y_2 \\ Y_2^\dagger & Y_3 \end{pmatrix},
$$
in the decomposition $\mathbb{C}^n = V_+ \oplus V_-$. Let $\Pi_X$ be the orthogonal projection onto $V_+$ so $I_n - \Pi_X$ is the orthogonal projection onto $V_-$. $\Pi_X$ is entirely determined by $X$. We have,
$$
\mathrm{tr}(Y\Pi_X) = \mathrm{tr}(Y_1), \qquad \mathrm{tr}(Y(I_n - \Pi_X)) = \mathrm{tr}(Y_3).
$$
Finally,
$$
d\mathrm{tr}(|X|)Y = \mathrm{tr}(Y\Pi_X) - \mathrm{tr}(Y(I_n - \Pi_X)) = \mathrm{tr}(Y(2\Pi_X - I_n)),
$$
or, with the usual scalar product,
$$
\nabla\mathrm{tr}(|X|) = 2\Pi_X - I_n.
$$
Notice that $X \mapsto \Pi_X$ is a smooth map onto the space of orthogonal projections of rank $k$. In particular, $\Pi_X = I_n$ if $k = n$, $\Pi_X = 0$ if $k = 0$. Finally, notice that $\nabla\mathrm{tr}(|X|)$ is always an orthogonal symmetry whose space of fixed point has dimension $k$.
